# Laptop screen has two shades down the middle. Is this graphics card or screen?

Tags: laptop, display

This suddenly happened right after I booted my laptop. This screen happens starts from the boot screen and stays on.

Is there anything I should try? Is this a screen problem or a settings problem?

I'm still under my one year warranty from Lenovo, are these kind of things covered under one year?

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you asking Lenovo?

Comment: @Xavierjazz, thanks I just contacted them. I just wanted to double check if there's anything on my end I can do before letting them take it for repair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can see the same also in BIOS setup screen if you enter it after computer reboot, then it is not important whether it is graphic card or display. You did not cause the damage by yourself so this should be covered by warranty.